# Pyspark.. Lag on generated/calculated column

Tags: pyspark, lag

I am trying to carry previously calculated column based on a condition.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = sc.parallelize([
    [1, 1 ],
    [1, 2 ],
    [3, 4 ],
    [4, 5 ],
    [1, 3 ]
]).toDF(('a', 'b' ))
```

When Col "a" has value <> 1, it should carry last known column B value corresponding to A (in this case 2). So The output should look like.

```
[1, 1 ],
[1, 2 ],
[3, 2 ],
[4, 2 ],
[1, 3 ]
```

how do we carry forward previous value.

appreciate help with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO trips. I recommend making an attempt yourself and editing your question to include your code when you get stuck. People are more likely to help if they don't feel like they are just doing the work for you.